# Codeigniter display 2 crud grocery table to 1 table

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Here are two tables.

i want make it to 1 table

[image]

I am new with codeigniter and crud grocery, 
my Golongan display 2 table, i don't have idea to resolve it

controller>Golongan.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Golongan extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('golongan');
        $crud->columns('idgol', 'jabatan', 'fasilitas');

        $crud->unset_delete();
        $crud->unset_edit();
        $crud->unset_add();
        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->load->view('golongan',$output);
        $this->render('golongan','full_width'); // (full_width) it must for load template
        }
}
```

> // if i deleted $this->load->view('golongan',$output); grocery crud
>   not appear,
>
> // if i deleted $this->render('golongan','full_width'); template
>   not appear
>
> //if i added both, there are 2 tables, i want make it into 1
>   table

view>golongan.php

```html
<?php 
foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
<script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo $output; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Please try this : $output = $crud->render(); $this->load->view('golongan',$output);  This is default of grocery crud. If default config is working fine then there is some human error. Thanks

Comment: yes, default crud grocery is working fine, but template is not appear, it means i need render (full_width)

Comment: Please comment the last line for a while :   $this->render('golongan','full_width');

Answer (score 0):

if you want display 2 tables in the same view...pass each output object to the view

Controller

```
  $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('Table2');
    $crud->columns('idgol', 'jabatan', 'fasilitas');

    $crud->unset_delete();
    $crud->unset_edit();
    $crud->unset_add();
    $data['output'] = $crud->render();

 $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('Table_2');
    $data['output_2'] = $crud->render();

    $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

in the view

```
       <?php 
foreach($output->css_files as $output->file): ?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $output->file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($output->js_files as $output->file): ?>
<script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo $output->output; ?>
<?php echo $output_2->output; ?>
```

Comment: fixed $$output to $output

Comment: Hi, I think he wants to display one one table, but two table appearing accidentally, because of two times rendering... Question is little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Hy fahmi, try this :

```html
public function index()
    {
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
        $crud->set_table('golongan');
        $crud->columns('idgol', 'jabatan', 'fasilitas');

        $crud->unset_delete();
        $crud->unset_edit();
        $crud->unset_add();
        $output = $crud->render();

  $view = 'golongan';
  $this->outputview->output_admin($view, $output);
        }
```

Comment: there is no render "full_width" it means that to load template

Answer (score 0):

class Golongan extends MY_Controller {

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
}
public function index()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('golongan');
    $crud->columns('idgol', 'jabatan', 'fasilitas');

    $crud->unset_delete();
    $crud->unset_edit();
    $crud->unset_add();
    $output = $crud->render();


    }
```

}